# Объясните, почему функция copy не сработала?

Tags: javascript

```js
var vasya = {
  age: 21,
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Петров'
};

var user = {
  isAdmin: false,
  isEmailConfirmed: true
};

var student = {
  university: 'My university'
};

// добавить к vasya свойства из user и student
copy(vasya, user, student);

alert( vasya.isAdmin ); // false
alert( vasya.university ); // My university
```

Comment: А Вы ее объявили ?

Comment: А почему она должна была сработать?

Comment: @andreymal https://learn.javascript.ru/arguments-pseudoarray#copy

Comment: @xes, так вы читайте там снизу реализация представлена. Это не стандартная функция!

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `copy` не сработала, так как она нигде не объявлена, об этом свидетельствует ошибка

> Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined

Которая появляется, если запустить твой сниппет в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерная реализация, если вы хотите свою функцию:

```
function copy(){
    if(arguments[0]){
        for(var i = 1;i < arguments.length;i++){
            for(key in arguments[i]){
                arguments[0][key] = arguments[i][key]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`copy(vasya, user, student)`

А вообще есть встроенная функция `Object.assign`

`var vasya = Object.assign(vasya, user, student);`